# Remove character at the end of column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How do you remove the comma at the end of the rows of a pandas column?

```
df.name
0    1. The, start,
1    2. Today's world
2    3. Today's world vs. yesterday.
```

Expected Output

```
df.name
0    1. The, start
1    2. Today's world
2    3. Today's world vs. yesterday.
```

```
df['name'] = df.name.str.rstrip(",")
```

Comment: And that doesn't work for you? Or do you need to assign back?

Comment: It doesn't work, even if I assign

Comment: Works with the sample data. Maybe you overlook trailing whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks Quang, yes hadn't realised about the trailing spaces it seems. Many thanks